# How can I extract the meta author and title from a docx exported from Google doc in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, metadata, google-docs, docx

I have created a `.docx` document on Google doc,

Using a script, I want to detect the meta for:

- author
- title
- date

I have already tried the following packages and I have opened issues because these packages don't work:

- [office-document-properties](https://github.com/swestmoreland/office-document-properties/issues/3)
- [docx-extractor](https://github.com/ndangles/docx-extractor/issues/1)

How can I extract the meta author and title from a google doc `.docx` document in NodeJS?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example,  retrieves the author, title and date (in your case, what date is?) from Google Document before export it as `.docx` file. In this case, this can be achieved using Drive API in Google APIs. How about this?

Comment: This package should work https://github.com/TorkelV/officeprops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .docx file is simply a zip file with other files within it.  Just find a package/module that can unzip it and look for the `.xml` file(s) that contains the data you need. ;)  You can unzip one yourself and take a look.  I used 7-zip to explore one and found two files with some document data in the `docProps` sub-path:

- app.xml
- core.xml

There are plenty to chose from I'm sure, but here is one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip

If you are exporting from a Google doc, then that information may not be included.

Comment: I have checked and there is no `app.xml` nore `core.xml` in the `.docx` produced on google doc. Also there is no information at all in any file produced by google doc. I bet those information cannot be retrieved.

Comment: `.docx` is NOT a Google document, it is a Microsoft Word document file. Google documents have a `.gdoc` extension. You may wish to review the actual files in question. You can also open it in a text editor, in case it is not compressed (I think older formats were just plain xml).

Comment: I am exporting the `.docx` in google doc. It's a requirement, I assume they don't set this information.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't seem like that information is included when created from a Google document (at least not in that path).  I only see document details in `word/document.xml`. None the less, that is the answer, even if the details are not there. ;) (and you never said you exported from Google)

Comment: Nope, it's not there for me either (for exported Google docs).

Comment: Do you get the author and the title? I don't. My question was regarding google doc, I'll have to wait until someone tell me how to set and get this information from google document

Comment: Then that is a different question, no? ;)  This was is referring to docx.

Comment: Does it have to be docx?

Comment: @JamesWilkins  how can i get the docx file back with the unzipped files(unzipped by`unzip`)?

Comment: I imagine you do the reverse, just zip the files and rename to `.docx`. ;)